# How to disable/enable the ActionBar.TabListener on some condition

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I have implemented ActionBar.TabListener with viewpager. Now I want to disable tab click for some condition
I have stopped swipe using TouchListner but want to do same for Tab Click.
Here is my code.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    ActionBar actionBar;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    String check ="";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdpter(fragmentManager));
        viewPager.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if ("".equals(check)) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
       actionBar =  getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);


        ActionBar.Tab tab1 = actionBar.newTab();
        tab1.setText("Tab 1");
        tab1.setTabListener(this);

        ActionBar.Tab tab2 = actionBar.newTab();
        tab2.setText("Tab 2");
        tab2.setTabListener(this);

        ActionBar.Tab tab3 = actionBar.newTab();
        tab3.setText("Tab 3");
        tab3.setTabListener(this);

        actionBar.addTab(tab1);
        actionBar.addTab(tab2);
        actionBar.addTab(tab3);

        viewPager.setCurrentItem(2, false);
    }


    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }
}
```

**MyAdpter.java**

```
class MyAdpter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

    public MyAdpter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        if(position==0){
            fragment = new FragmentA();
        }
        if(position==1){
            fragment = new FragmentB();
        }
        if(position==2){
            fragment = new FragmentC();
        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

**FragmentA.java**

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a , container,false);
    }
}
```

**FragmentB/FragmentC are similar to FragmentA**

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

**ScreenShot**

[image]

Comment: what are the scenarios when you exactly like to disable the touch listener?

Comment: Since you are managing everything with a tabs number its not possible, the work around is to perform clicks on other tab when the tabs you want to be disabled will clicked

Comment: How can I disable the listener on tabs?

Comment: You can do workaround like when user clicks on tab 2 when it was disable then just redirect him to the tab which is enable,  if you will give me a scenario then i will be able to explain you more clearly. You cant simply disable listeners for particular events

Comment: There is a variable named "check" which must not be empty. If it is empty then Tab1 and Tab2 are not clickable... and by-default Tab three will be active

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this..

in OnCheckedChanged listener for checkbox, you can specify which tabs are enable..

just by doing

```
// to enable
tabLayout.getChildAt(position).setEnabled(true);

// or to disable
tabLayout.getChildAt(position).setClickable(false);.
```

use this property to enable or disable clicks on tab.

Comment: What is 'tabLayout' here?

Comment: see, whatever you are using with actionbar is basically added to tablayout, its android design widget. for that widget you can use this methods.  for your case, you can use tablayout with viewpager and save your purpose as actionbar tabs doesnt support this methods of enabling disabling.. you can get started with this **https://guides.codepath.com/android/google-play-style-tabs-using-tablayout** its too easy to use.